# Is there a way to add url with path variable in FilterRegistrationBean?

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter

I have the following api:

```
/api/bank/{accounts}/ministatement_report_generate
```

The accounts can be 1 to N integer values separated by commas.

```
Example:  /api/bank/23,24,25/ministatement_report_generate
```

Now I have a **FilterRegistrationBean**

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean signedURLFilter(){
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(publicUrlFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/reports/*","/api/bank/{accounts}/ministatement_report_generate/*");
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

This does not work for the url with the path variable. I have tried using regex and something like /api/bank/*/ministatement_report_generate. But, nothing seems to work.

Is there any workaround? (I cannot keep **/api/bank/*** as there are api's similar to this which does not require filter)